# Visual Studio Code App Center: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I used Visual Studio Code App Center for Building my android apps, It was ok after but now build failed with below exception. How can I fix this issue?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you are using `Visual Studio Code App Center`, you may face the same kind of issue when you use JAVA 11 in your android project. If you are looking a solution for MS App Center issue, This may help you!

1. Go to https://appcenter.ms/users/user1/apps/yourapp/build/branches
2. Click settings icon to go to `Build configuration`
3. Scroll down to `Environment` and turn on.
4. Set `JAVA_HOME` to `$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)`

[image]

Comment: What for macOS?

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena What's the error?

Comment: I am unable to run  new react native projects in VisualStudio Code (latest: 1.71.2). This is specifically in Android because it uses JDK 11 internally using Gradle Settings, and this setting is not exposed externally to VisualStudio Code. I have to always open Android Studio (Dolphin) in order to run them.

Comment: ...This way I am also unable to use ReactNative debugger in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena this is not for vs code, this is for appcenter

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will retry my search for Specific Visual Studio Code solutions.

Comment: i got another error related to compiling firebase packages with java on appcenter, and this solution works for me

Comment: What about for Windows OS (10)? So it has to do with the environment variables?

Comment: I spent over a week to solve this issue, finally this answer helped me. Thanx.

Comment: What's the solution for the mac?